# Passing value from datasource to onclick event

Tags: google-app-maker

I would like to direct a user to a page within an app using a field value from a model. The model is loaded into a grid and the user makes a selection to navigate to a page within the app based on images displayed in the grid cells.

I am thinking to use the app.showPage(app.pages.Page) for the onClick event and passing in the page the user should be directed from the model as a parameter such as widget.datasource.item.PageName.

Can you suggest how the name of the page could be passed in from the datasource as as variable to the onClick event accomplish this navigation?

Will appreciate any help!

Answer (score 0):

Lets say you are storing your page names in your datasource under a field PageName (string field) such as YourPageName1, YourPageName2, etc. Then for your onClick event all you would need is:

```
app.showPage(app.pages[widget.datasource.item.PageName]);
```

Comment: @Gabe glad this worked for you. If you don't mind please mark the answer as accepted as this helps increase SO users such as myself with our reputation level. Thank you.

Comment: Markus, I did that immediately but my reputation level is not yet at 15 so it is not letting me accept the answer. I wish it did as your answer is perfect!